# osx and openssl md5

Tags: gcc, openssl, osx-snow-leopard

I use gcc version `4.2.1` and openssl version `0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011` and I tried out the following code snippet

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<openssl/md5.h>
int main() {
    char test[] = "test";
    unsigned char d[16];

    MD5_CTX c;
    MD5_Init(&c);
    MD5_Update(&c, (char *)test, strlen(test));
    MD5_final(d, &c);
}
```

Compiling as `gcc -o t <filename.c>` gets me the following error :-

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_MD5_Update", referenced from:
      _main in ccxSwMKm.o
  "_MD5_Init", referenced from:
      _main in ccxSwMKm.o
  "_MD5_final", referenced from:
      _main in ccxSwMKm.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You probably need to link with some libssl...

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `-lcrypto` to the command line.